# SSRS and PostgreSQL: How do I pass an optional parameter?

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, parameters, dataset, ssrs-2012

I'm using a PostgreSQL ODBC data source in an SSRS report.

From my previous knowledge with MS SQL Server data sources, to pass an optional parameter to a SSRS dataset query, you would do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeField = @Param1 OR @Param1 IS NULL
```

The key was using `OR @Param1 IS NULL` which basically bypasses the `SomeField = @Param1` part and effectively acts as an "optional" filter.  However, this doesn't seem to work when using a PostgreSQL ODBC data source (not sure if it's due to Postgres or ODBC or both).  I get an error when clicking on Refresh Fields, or when executing/previewing the report.

This might be partly due to not being able to pass named parameters into the SQL, but instead having to use "?" like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeField = ?
```

...which makes it impossible to do `OR ? IS NULL` basically.

So, anybody know how I might be able to pass optional parameters to a PostgreSQL data set in SSRS?

Comment: Hmm, I think I may have realized what I did wrong.  Turns out this works rather well:  `WHERE (somefield = ? OR CAST(? AS <somefield's data type>) IS NULL)`.  So, the CAST on the parameter `?` is necessary, otherwise the SSRS tooling gives you an error of unknown data type.  And I have to use 2 parameters in the Data Set to refer to the same parameter twice (because of 2 `?` references in the WHERE clause), but that's not terrible.  Don't know why I didn't think of casting before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a specific ODBC solution but a workaround. This will work if `SomeField` can not be `null`:

```
select *
from mytable
where somefield = coalesce(?, somefield)
```

If `SomeField` can be `null` and you want to return nulls:

```
where somefield is not distinct from coalesce(?, somefield)
```

Check [`is distinct from`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thanks.  However, I can see how it will work when SomeField is not nullable.  But if it is nullable, it won't work, because `where somefield = NULL` won't match null values (as oposed to `where somefield IS NULL`).  And if I need it to act like an "optional" parameter, then NULL values should be returned as well (when the parameter is not specified).

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I'm still learning PostgreSQL, so I wasn't familiar with `is [not] distinct from`.  Very cool.

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong (see comments in my original post above), but I'll mark this as an answer because it works well too, and is pretty clean.